# Xbee Series 1 with no Coordinator

Tags: xbee

Isn't it mandatory by the 802.15.4 standard that a network must have a coordinator? How do two end devices in an XBee series 1 network communicate without having a coordinator?

Addition to question:
I do understand that I can configure them with no coordinator. However since Xbee 802.15.4 complies to the 802.15.4 standard specifications, there MUST be a coordinator.
Read the standard at: standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.15.4-2011.pdf

Quoting:

> In the star topology, the communication is established between devices
>   and a single central controller, called the PAN coordinator.

and

> The peer-to-peer topology also has a PAN coordinator; however, it
>   differs from the star topology in that any device is able to
>   communicate with any other device as long as they are in range of one
>   another.

and

> In a peer-to-peer topology, each device is capable of communicating
>   with any other device within its radio communications range. One
>   device is nominated as the PAN coordinator, for instance, by virtue of
>   being the first device to communicate on the channel.

Does the XBee firmware by itself assign the first to connect as a coordinator?

Comment: It is mandatory.  How are you forming a network with two end devices an no coordinator?  A true end device (RFD or reduced-function device) can only communicate with a parent FFD (full-function device).

Comment: @tomlogic for two xbees, using default xbee configuration, I can set both pan id to one id,  set MY1=DL2 and MY2=DL1. Default configuration has CE=0 so all devices are end devices. They will communicate. Is it in the xbee firmware that the first xbee to create a network becomes a coordinator automatically?

Comment: No as stated below. There does NOT need to be a coordinator

Answer (score 0):

To get the full functionality of a IEEE 802.15.4 network, including for example support for RFD's and beacon mode communication, you need a coordinator.

However, if you don't need those things you can do fine without a coordinator.

If you want 16-bit addressing you will probably need some kind of "master device" anyway to assign addresses on the PAN.